# Nullifying a chametz-based medication before Pesach

Tags: halacha, passover, mysticism-kabbalah, choleh-sick, bitul-batel-null

Let's say you are a choleh who is permitted or required to take a chometz-containing medication during Pesach (according to the halachos described here: http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-passover-medicine.htm ). Let's imagine, furthermore, that yours is a medication that is somehow based on chometz in terms of its function or ability to heal.

My question is this: When you make the nullification on your chometz before Pesach starts, is the chometz of your medication understood as being "nullified" in an absolute sense, too--whereby, mystically speaking, your medicine should not work for you?

(I understand this is a case of abstractions upon abstractions -- but I still wonder if there is a source that deals with this. Otherwise it would seem that the nullification process could be confusing, even scary, for those hypothetically in this situation. I am looking for a textual source for the exact sense and extent of bitul in light of these hypothetical concerns.)

Comment: There are (at least) two views on what ביטול does: either it will make the chametz "not chametz," or it will make it not yours. See Rashi and Tosfos somewhere in the beginning of Pesachim (don't recall where, exactly; maybe [4a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=4&format=pdf)?).

Comment: Thanks @Shokhet. I'd be interested to hear if any mystical sources get into the nitty-gritty of how making it "not chametz" could affect its power to heal

Comment: Don;t understand the question. The "nullification" is not magic. It's simply saying "I don't own the Chametz anymore" - and it's like dust, meaning that I have no intention re-owning it simply because it's on my property.

Comment: @DannySchoemann Yes; I guess I am looking for a textual source for the exact sense and extent of *bitul* in light of these hypothetical concerns.